# How to center a relative div?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to get the following code working for hours, without success... Could you please help me to get the projects div centered (even when the page is zoomed in and out)?

Here is my HTML & CSS:

```css
#bottom {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-color: #FFF;}
 
#secondsection {
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-size: cover;
 color: #eaeaf0;
 margin-left: 7%;
 margin-right: 7%;
 padding-top: 35px;
 padding-bottom: 35px;
 position: relative;}

#ss_top {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;}

.ss_title {
 display: inline;
 float:left;
 color: #000000;
 font-family: 'Eurostile';
 font-size: 35px;
 text-transform: uppercase;}

.ss_title2 {
 color: #a5a5a5;}

#gallerybutton {
 position: relative;
 display: inline;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 0%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;}

#projects {
 position: relative;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 max-width: 2000px;
 padding: 175px 0px 0px 0px;}

#pr_one, #pr_two {
 display: block;}

.pr_img {
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 margin-right: 1%;
 margin-bottom: 1%;}

#viewprofilebutton {
 position: relative;
    left: -75px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
    margin-bottom: 2.5%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;}
```

```html
<div id="secondsection">
     
 <div id="ss_top">
  <p class="ss_title">A selection of projects<br /><span class="ss_title2">I've worked on lately</span></p>
   <button type="button" id="gallerybutton">See everything</button>
 </div>

 <div id="projects">
 <div id="pr_one">
  <div class="pr_img"><a target="_blank" href=""><img src="images/pr_nfs.jpg" alt="" width="488px" height="272px"></a></div>
     <div class="pr_img"><a target="_blank" href=""><img src="images/pr_nfs.jpg" alt="" width="488px" height="272px"></a></div>
        <div class="pr_img"><a target="_blank" href=""><img src="images/pr_nfs.jpg" alt="" width="488px" height="272px"></a></div>
 </div>
 <div id="pr_two">
  <div class="pr_img"><a target="_blank" href=""><img src="images/pr_nfs.jpg" alt="" width="488px" height="272px"></a></div>
  <div class="pr_img"><a target="_blank" href=""><img src="images/pr_nfs.jpg" alt="" width="488px" height="272px"></a></div>
      <div class="pr_img"><a target="_blank" href=""><img src="images/pr_nfs.jpg" alt="" width="488px" height="272px"></a></div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <a href="#thirdsection"><button type="button" id="viewprofilebutton">See my work</button></a>

</div>
```

Comment: How do you want your images to display, two rows of three images wide? If so, you page will be approximately 3x488 px wide. Please elaborate.

Comment: Well, if possible I would like to have two rows wide for small screens and three wide for larger screens. The point is that no matter if I scroll in or out, the projects div sticks to the left side of the screen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start.  Look at the following CSS:

```css
#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;}

#secondsection {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #eaeaf0;
    margin-left: 7%;
    margin-right: 7%;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dotted red;
}

#ss_top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    overflow: auto;
}
#ss_top p {
    margin: 0;
}

.ss_title {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Eurostile';
    font-size: 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;}

.ss_title2 {
    color: #a5a5a5;}

#gallerybutton {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;}

#projects {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 2000px;
    padding: 175px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}

#pr_one, #pr_two {
    display: block;
    border: 2px dashed blue;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.pr_img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}
.pr_img img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#viewprofilebutton {
    position: relative;
    left: -75px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
    margin-bottom: 2.5%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;}
```

I started by getting rid of the floats in the title, `#ss_top`, you don't need it.

For the `#projects` panel with the images, floats are getting you into trouble with
centering.

On `#pr_one` and `#pr_two`, add `text-align: center` and then use `display: inline-block` on `.pr_img`, this will center align your images (give/take some margins), and then apply a suitable width of say `30%` so that the images auto scale to form a row of three.

The trick now is to apply `display: inline-block` to the images (`.pr_img img`) so you 
can now use margins to control top/bottom/left/right spacing.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/rmtpy6t0/

**Note:** You still have some polishing up to do but at least this clarifies the issues related to centering and floated elements.

**Responsive Design:** If you want 2 or 3 images in a row depending on the screen size, you need to learn about media queries.  However, because you wrapped 3 images in a `div`, you are locked into 3 per row, but that may be okay.

Comment: One more question, though (sorry lol): I currently have three sections on my website. The first section is a full-screen section/intro page. But after adding the new code, the (second) projects section is now floating over the first section. Any idea on how to fx that?

Comment: Wild guess: Add `overflow: auto` to the CSS rule styling the block level parent of your first section.  You probably have some floats in there that need to be constrained within the parent block.

Comment: I just found the issue: I accidentally removed the id symbol before the bottom div. Everything is fine now, thank you very much for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center your pictures, make changes in your css:

```
.pr_img {
  /* float: left; */
  display: block;
  /* margin-right: 1%; */
  /* margin-bottom: 1%; */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto add margin:auto

```
#projects {
    position: relative;
    margin:auto;
    max-width: 2000px;
    padding: 175px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.pr_img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

tell me if it works

edit: yep.

works :) 
http://jsfiddle.net/max7j84m/

Answer (score 0):

```
  .pr_img {
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It's work for me