# Centering a Slideshow with CSS

Tags: css, image, slideshow, centering

I am not a coder by any means, I have very very little training and get by only with what I can pick up online. With that said, I apologize if this is a dumb question! I am a photographer who makes these slideshows for clients when their images are ready and I am having an issue getting them to center (horizontally) on whatever the page it is being displayed on. In my viewing galleries there are several different page widths, so even if I center manually using (i.e.: left 95px) or whatever it is for that page it obviously won't work on a different page with different site width. I am sure there is an easy universal command I can add to all of these slideshows that will make them center on every page but I can't figure it out -- any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is the code I am working with...

```
<style>
    .ss-embed-container-89670 {
        position:relative; padding-bottom:680px; 
        height:0; overflow:hidden; max-width:1020px} .ss-embed-container-89670 
        iframe {position:absolute; top:0;left:0; width:100%!important; 
        height:100%!important;
    } 
</style>
<div class="ss-embed-container-89670"><iframe src="https://greg-
    ross.smartslides.com/morgan-clayton?pt=ed" frameborder="0" 
    webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try to do something like this:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="ss-embed-container-89670"><iframe src="https://greg-
        ross.smartslides.com/morgan-clayton?pt=ed" frameborder="0" 
        webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Gabriel, for such a quick response! I just tried your solution and for some reason now the slideshow is not appearing. I am going over it to see if I can figure out why. Do you see anything obvious as to why it might be breaking?

Comment: it is probably because of position: relative in your css. Try to take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888354/how-to-center-a-relative-div